# null request response in simple jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, null, httprequest

I am trying to just set up a very basic jsp file that takes in a query from a url and displays it. I have the following test.jsp file that I run on the server:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test jsp</title>
</head>
<body>
<% String firstName = (String) request.getAttribute("firstName"); 
out.println("Hello :" + firstName);%>

</body>
</html>
```

However, when I type in the following URL, I still get a "null" result (even after refreshing): see [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeeZF.jpg).

Note: my ultimate goal is to do have an event at some point that sends a POST request from a java file and display its result in the jsp page. If I understood well from my research, I would have to do it via a Servlet with a DispacherRequest forwarding method. But I first want to understand why the simple aforementioned code isnt working).

Thank you for your help !

Comment: a simple servlet would do the job, but if you use a framework such as struts, spring or stripes then they will usually use a DispacherRequest forwarding method.  **definitely the goal to aim for**

Answer (score 2):

You mention that you're trying to display a query parameter from the URL. A query or request *parameter* is not the same as a request *attribute*.

To get a query parameter, you would have to use the [`getParameter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-) method:

```
String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName")
```

Comment: My bad, you are right. It works now. Sorry for the inconvenience !